# LiveCharts 2 : Emoji not displayed in graphs

Tags: c#, maui, livecharts

In LiveCharts 2.0.0-beta.7.10, I'm having issues displaying Emojis when they are data labels. See below :

[image]

There is a "Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Russian" link (https://lvcharts.com/docs/Maui/2.0.0-beta.710/samples.axes.labelsFormat2) in LiveCharts 2's page, I assumed to be helpful about special characters, but this didn't help me.

Step to reproduce :

1. Create a new MAUI .NET App (I used .NET 7)
2. Add the LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Maui 2.0.0-beta.701 nugget (prerelease must be ticked)
3. Then add it in the MauiProgram.cs :
   `using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.Hosting;`
   And :

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
   var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
   builder
       .UseMauiApp<App>()
       // vvv
       .UseSkiaSharp(true)
       [...]
 }
```

4. In the XAML, add the namespace : in the Content tag:

```
xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Maui;assembly=LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Maui"
```

And add the chart itself :
`<lvc:PieChart x:Name="crtPieEmojisSent"/>`

5. Populate the chart :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    // Pie Chart Series
    ObservableCollection<ISeries> SeriesChart = new ObservableCollection<ISeries>();

    PieSeries<double?> aSeries;

    aSeries = new PieSeries<double?> { Values = new List<double?> { 10 }, Name = "Value 1" };
    SeriesChart.Add(aSeries);

    aSeries = new PieSeries<double?> { Values = new List<double?> { 5 }, Name = "Value 2" };
    SeriesChart.Add(aSeries);

    // Note : Replace the :) by a real emoji, somehow, Stackoverflow tells me the code is invalid if I post a real emoji
    aSeries = new PieSeries<double?> { Values = new List<double?> { 5 }, Name = "Emoji :) (Not Working)" };
    SeriesChart.Add(aSeries);

    // UI : Bind the chart
    crtPieEmojisSent.Series = SeriesChart;
}
```

Any ideas ?

EDIT : I posted the question on the GitHub here https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2/issues/1022 and managed to have a piece of the answer, but not everything (at least yet). I'm updating the progress just in case it helps someone;

The owner told me I needed to use a font that supports Emoji, so I changed the font to fonts that display emojis (in MS Word), like this :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // Pie Chart Series
        ObservableCollection<ISeries> SeriesChart = new ObservableCollection<ISeries>();

        PieSeries<double?> aSeries;

        aSeries = new PieSeries<double?> { Values = new List<double?> { 10 }, Name = "Value 1" };
        SeriesChart.Add(aSeries);

        aSeries = new PieSeries<double?> { Values = new List<double?> { 5 }, Name = "Value 2" };
        SeriesChart.Add(aSeries);

        aSeries = new PieSeries<double?> { Values = new List<double?> { 5 }, Name = "Emoji  (Not Working)" };
        SeriesChart.Add(aSeries);

        // Define the fonts for the legend and Tooltip
        SolidColorPaint legendAndTooltipFont = new SolidColorPaint
        {
            Color = new SKColor(0, 0, 0),
            SKTypeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Times New Roman")
        };

        crtPieEmojisSent.TooltipTextPaint = legendAndTooltipFont;
        crtPieEmojisSent.LegendTextPaint = legendAndTooltipFont;

        // UI : Bind the chart
        crtPieEmojisSent.Series = SeriesChart;
    }
```

The font changes accordingly but the blank square stays the same BUT changes depending on the font used :

- Arial : Square
- Calibri : Square with a Question Mark in it
- Comic Sans MS (I know...) : Square
- Times New Roman : Square

So I guess *something* is happening but the display is not right.

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect this will work?  I don't see the term `emoji` mentioned anywhere in their docs or repo.

Comment: Even though emojis (emoticons) have been assigned Unicode values, you'll need a font that includes those glyphs. NOTE: will display in a single color, same as other text, since a font only contains strokes; no color info. Search for an "emoji font", and for instructions how to use a different font in livecharts.

Comment: I thought emoji were common enough to be supported seemlessly. Good thinking ToolmakerSteve, maybe the font LiveCharts uses does not support emojis. I'll update the post if I come to a solution